# c# code error The name 'i' does not exist

Tags: c#

in line

```
 urls[i] =  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
```

it say Error 1 The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

how can I fix it

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MyConString = "SERVER=192.168.0.78;" +
             "DATABASE=webboard;" +
             "UID=aimja;" +
             "PASSWORD=aimjawork;" +
             "charset=utf8;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT  url FROM `listweb` WHERE `url` IS NOT NULL AND ( `webbordkind` = '¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿' ) and `nourl`= 'n' order by province, amphore limit 4 ";
        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        string[] urls = new string[2];
        string thisrow = "";
        string sumthisrow = "";
        string urlname ;
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            thisrow = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                thisrow +=  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                urlname = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

                urls[i] =  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); 

          //  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\file.txt", thisrow + " " + Environment.NewLine);
            sumthisrow = sumthisrow + thisrow;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing braces here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    thisrow +=  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    urlname = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    urls[i] = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); 
}
```

I'd also advise you *not* to create strings by concatenating in a loop. Put them in a `List<string>` first then at the end convert it to an array (except in .NET 4.0 or newer where this step is not required) and use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx). As well as giving better performance this allows allows you to add a separator between the fields, which I assume you want...

If you don't need a separator then you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add braces to your for loop otherwise it only loops the first statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    thisrow +=  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    urlname = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    urls[i] =  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: No worries mate! :-) Since you beat me to the answer, i thought i will make myself useful atleast in some way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your braces are missing for the FOR loop. The variable i is available only within the FOR loop which is only one line after your loop in your case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    thisrow +=  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    urlname = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();

    urls[i] =  Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
}
```